# Merge SQL Rows (add their percentages)

Tags: sql

I'm an absolute SQL noob but my boss has asked me to make some updates to queries for our dashboards (metabase->datalab)

My tables are quite simple but any answers I found here were merging null values which doesn't apply so I wasn't sure if they would be correct.

```
WITH c as (
  SELECT "institution", count(*) as cnt 
  FROM "public"."students" 
  WHERE "institution" IS NOT NULL 
  AND "institution" != ''
)
SELECT institution, 100.0*cnt/(SELECT sum(cnt) FROM c) AS percent 
FROM c 
ORDER BY percent 
DESC LIMIT 10;
```

table was generated from the code and produced these results:

```
institute     | percent
uniA          | 12.95
uniA (UNIA)   |  4.3
```

The two rows are actually the same institute, but from different versions of our database and so have different names. I want to combine the rows and end up with a congregate percentage of 17.25

Comment: Sorry i don't know what are you asking. How many tables are you using and what do you want to do. and what do you mean by (WITH c as) at the beginning you are using. Can you explain me what do you want and what is your table and table columns name and what data you want to retrieve by using this query.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` with aggregation:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN institution = 'uniA (UNIA)' THEN 'uniA'
             ELSE institution
        END) as institution,
       COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS percent 
FROM public.students s 
WHERE institution <> ''   -- also removed `NULL` values
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN institution = 'uniA (UNIA)' THEN 'uniA'
               ELSE institution
          END)
ORDER BY percent DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

You don't need the CTE.  Also note that I replaced the subquery with window functions.